# How to ignore an unknown class when using RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, rest, serialization, resttemplate

I'm using Spring RestTemplate to retrieve informations from a rest server. The call is as follow:

```
SyncInfo[] result = restTemplate.getForObject(url, SyncInfo[].class, param1, param2);
```

SyncInfo is a parent class, with lots of childrens, let's call them

```
ClassA extends SyncInfo
ClassB extends SyncInfo
ClassC extends SyncInfo
```

It works very well.

My problem is that sometimes, the server is updated with new kind of object. For example, it could return a list with a ClassD which also extends SyncInfo.

My program doesn't know what is a ClassD object and the call fails.

Is there a way to tell the RestTemplate object to ignore unknown class? Just deserialize the one you can and ignore the others?

Because the only other way is to create the class in my code so it will be able to deserialize it but it's kind of dirty because my code don't need this class and it creates a dependency between my code and the server, which I don't like.

Comment: This doesn't exactly answer your question, but this method for handling JSON response errors might point you in the right direction:  http://springinpractice.com/2013/10/07/handling-json-error-object-responses-with-springs-resttemplate

Comment: Would it be possible to create a generic version of this class and method and parameterize it like `T extends SyncInfo`?

Comment: will, can you explain yourself with an example and in an answer?